# Check energy using Schrodingers stationary state equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, schroedinger-equation

Currently going through an old question which concerns a particle of mass $m$ on the interval $[-a,a]$ with potential $V=V_0$. In the question it says to show that the energy levels of the particle are $E=V_0+\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{8ma^2}$, but after numerous tries and checks I keep getting $E=V_0+\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2ma^2}$, just want to check that the answer in the question isn't just wrong so I stop wasting my time trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: Width of that potential is $2a$.

Comment: Okay so does that mean I've made an error somewhere?

Comment: No. But if you in your result replace $a^2$ by $4d^2$, you get the first formula.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the barrier

$\psi''  = \frac{\sqrt{2m(E-V)}}{\hbar }$

Where the general solution is

$A\sin{ka} + B\cos{ka}$

where even parity implies

$\psi(-a) = \psi(a)$

Therefore

$A\sin{ka} + B\cos{ka}= -A\sin{ka} + B\cos{ka}$

$A\sin{ka} = -A\sin{ka}$ and this is only true if $A\sin{ka}=0$ and this implies that $B\cos{ka}=0$

Your textbook is showing a solution which can be derived

A is positive because it must give a positive solution for x not equal to a

Therefore $sin(ka) = 0 $ and B = 0

$k = \frac{n\pi}{2a}$

$\frac{\sqrt{2m(E-V)}}{\hbar } = \frac{n\pi}{2a}$

$\frac{2m(E)}{\hbar }= V + \frac{n^2\pi^2}{4a^2}$

$E_n = \frac{\hbar n^2\pi^2}{8ma^2}$